What's "jam" mean in "The room reeled and he jammed his head down" (as well as the sentence itself)?
This is a sample sentence from the Collins Dictionary for the verb "reel" in the sense of "spin":

The room reeled and he jammed his head down.

What does he jammed his head down mean?
jam:
2
: to push forcibly
jammed the shovel into the ground (Merriam-Webster)
I understand this sentence as "The room was spinning (because he was dizzy perhaps) and he pushed his head downward. Is that correct?

"to jam one's head down" is not a collocation in American English so I could only guess what it means.   Put his chin down hard against his sternum (to steady himself)? Fell and struck his head on the floor?

I've frequently come across "to jam one's foot down" (generally in a motoring context) but never "to jam one's head down".

Note, sometimes the sample sentences in dictionaries just come from internet usages and are collected automatically. That's why there's a little warning label suggesting that you shouldn't sue if they're offensive, and can report mistakes. I'm having trouble finding this example on Collins, or anywhere on the internet. Perhaps it's already been reported and replaced?

Your interpretation is correct - the person quickly and forcibly lowered their head because they felt dizzy. That said, I do find the use of "jam" a little unusual here, as that typically implies forcibly putting something into something else, or into some specific position. But here, there's little indication of exactly how/where the person's head is being jammed. It sounds fine to "jam your finger down on the button", or "jam your foot down on the pedal", or even just "jam your foot down" (as the floor or ground is implied) but to simply "jam your head down" strikes me as odd without more context. It's hard to imagine a person's neck moving their own head in a "jamming" motion. It implies a sudden movement, but it's hard to reconcile with the pushing movement typically associated with jamming. It might be OK with greater context, but as an isolated sentence it's not exactly clear how the person is moving their head (Chin to chest? Forehead to desk? Into a bucket of water?).

Without context the sentence "he jammed his head down" would suggest to me it was someone's else's head he was jammimg. It is difficult to conceive of jammimng one's own head - as you point out.

@WS2 unless it's truncated, something like "he jammed his head down between the cushions"

I think it's relevant that this sentence appeared in the definition of "reel", not "jam", so the lexicographer probably didn't worry too much about that clause.
